# How to view all queries in MemSQL or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, singlestore

How can I view a list/history of all queries in a database/cluster in MemSQL or MySQL including completed and on-going running queries? I would like to see the status of any query such as if it completed or if it is running or if it has been aborted. Is there a query that I can run to view this? Thank you.

Comment: You can use `show [full] processlist` for currently running queries. For finished queries, you’ll have to enable the query log.

Comment: Thank you. Will that command display 'running' queries as well as 'aborted' queries? How can I enable the query log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MemSQL has information_schema views to get info about running and completed/failed queries. Take a look at https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.0/workload-profiling/.

For example the following query will show all the queries that have been run in the last 10 minutes:
`select query_text,success_count,failure_count from information_schema.mv_activities_cumulative join information_schema.mv_queries using (activity_name) where last_finished_timestamp > now() - interval '10' minute;`

You can also use these views to drill deeper to understand the resource usage of queries.

Answer (score 0):

According to official memsql documentation on [Management View Reference](https://docs.memsql.com/v7.0/concepts/workload-profiling/management-view-reference/) they say "mv_activities determines recent resource use by computing the change in mv_activities_cumulative over an interval of time. This interval is controlled by the value of the activities_delta_sleep_s session variable."

So something like this if I read the documentation correctly should upon execution set the variable activities_delta_sleep_s to 30 seconds and then when the query is run you will see all database activities in decreasing cpu time. My problem with it is that I don't seem to see all of the activities I perform and a lot of the query text is blank. The activities_delta_sleep_s according to memsql [forums](https://www.memsql.com/forum/t/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-successful-and-failed-queries-for-a-recent-interval-say-5-mins/536) indicates that the variable simple makes all management view calls sleep for this variable amount of time before returning results. I think the idea there is that this would allow the for the aggregation of activities in nodes and network traffic.

```
#set the lookback period desired
set activities_delta_sleep_s = 30;

#This query is supposed to show resource costs of server activities, but not sure how to ID specific queries.
SELECT * #look at QUERY_TEXT
from information_schema.MV_ACTIVITIES a
LEFT JOIN information_schema.mv_queries q ON a.ACTIVITY_NAME = q.ACTIVITY_NAME
order by 4 DESC;
```